# AngularJS - combining form fields

Tags: angularjs, time, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a dynamic form where I can enter a duration in hh:mm:ss format.

I would like to store that value as seconds.

I don't see an angular input type that allows for a duration style time (just dates), so I appear to left with either using a fixed date and just extracting a time in seconds from that date, or using 3 separate number fields (hh, mm, ss) and having a hidden field containing the converted seconds.

Is there any easy way to achieve this second method? I can't see anyway around having to either create second scope for storing these temp values or cleaning them from scope when I submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a validator and a filter for your custom field. You can only have one input for this. The validator will check that the value is entered in format like {0-24}:{0-60}:{0-60} and store seconds in the model. And filter will convert seconds to your desired format. What you can also add is a placeholder for format, or even better a formatter, that will help user write the input (add : automatically). If you will need any other calculations or variables, it is better to use isolated scope, but in this example, I don't see the need for that.

Answer (score 0):

Like indicated in the other answer, you can use ng-pattern directive with the {0-24}:{0-60}:{0-60} as regex.

Then use either filter on that field or custom method that can pick up the three values on change.